# Argparse error with TensorFlow's cifar10.py

Tags: argparse, tensorflow

I get the following error when I run `python cifar10.py`:

`argparse.ArgumentError: argument --batch_size: conflicting option string(s): --batch_size`

Here's the full output of the run including a complete trace:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.0 locally                          
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.6.5 locally                           
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.0 locally                           
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally                                
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.0 locally                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "cifar10.py", line 54, in <module>                                                                                          
    """Number of images to process in a batch.""")                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_flags.py", line 86, in DEFINE_integer           
    _define_helper(flag_name, default_value, docstring, int)                                                                       
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_flags.py", line 60, in _define_helper           
    type=flagtype)                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1297, in add_argument                                                                
    return self._add_action(action)                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1671, in _add_action                                                                 
    self._optionals._add_action(action)                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1498, in _add_action                                                                 
    action = super(_ArgumentGroup, self)._add_action(action)                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1311, in _add_action                                                                 
    self._check_conflict(action)                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1449, in _check_conflict                                                             
    conflict_handler(action, confl_optionals)                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1456, in _handle_conflict_error                                                      
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)                                                                         
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --batch_size: conflicting option string(s): --batch_size
```

This error seems to come from the following line in `cifar10.py`: `tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128, """Number of images to process in a batch.""")`

It seems like the `argparse` library thinks that I've already defined the option string `--batch_size`, but I haven't.

[Stack: Amazon g2.2xlarge spot instance, Python 2.7.6]

Comment: The code that you have written might not have defined this string, but something in the `cifar10` calling stack has.  You probably need to review the API for that function.  One module is probably importing another, and both are populating the same `parser`.

Comment: Thanks! Ill look for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `cifr10.py` file:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10_input

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

# Basic model parameters.
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
....
```

The error is produced by this last statement, which, in the `_flags.py` file, defines an `argparse` argument with that name.  Evidently at this point the `tf.app` already has such an argument define.

So we need to look further back at `import tensorflow as tf` to see how `tf.app` was created?

What's the `Amazon g2.2xlarge`?  Could that defining `batch_size` as well?

Looks like `tf.app` comes from

```
tensorflow/python/platform/app.py
```

which in turn gets it from something like

```
from tensorflow.python.platform.google._app import *
```

So if you are running this on some `google` or `amazon` platform that itself accepts `batch_size` parameter, it could produce this error.

---

Another question about `cifr10` and the `batch_size` argument:

[How to use "FLAGS" (command line switches) in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241827/how-to-use-flags-command-line-switches-in-tensorflow)

Same error here:

[Tensorflow ArgumentError Running CIFAR-10 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734054/tensorflow-argumenterror-running-cifar-10-example)
The answer says to use `cifar10_train.py`,`cifar10_eval.py`, not `cifar10.py`.