# How can I use subcommands with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, argparse

I want to write a toolkit around TensorFlow which streamlines the process of model creation / testing. There are multiple subtasks such as `train` and `test`. I want to have one command `tv` (TensorVision) and have subcommands (`tv train`, `tv test` - there might come more).

Usually, I would do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
tv, the TensorVision toolkit, is a computer vision toolbox.

It includes scripts that are useful for building tools for computer vision
tasks such as classification.
"""


import argparse

# tv modules
# Every TV tool that should be available through
#   tv TOOL
# has to be added to ``get_parser()`` and to ``main``.
import tensorvision
from tensorvision import train
from tensorvision import test


def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
                                     prog='tv')
    parser.add_argument('--version',
                        action='version',
                        version=('hwrt %s' % str(tensorvision.__version__)))
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
    subparsers.add_parser('train',
                          add_help=False,
                          parents=[train.get_parser()],
                          help=("Train a model."))
    subparsers.add_parser('test',
                          add_help=False,
                          parents=[test.get_parser()],
                          help=("Test a model."))
    return parser


def main(args):
    """Run the requested module."""
    if args.cmd == 'train':
        # train.main(args.model)
        train.main()
    elif args.cmd == 'test':
        test.main(args.whatever, args.foo)
    else:
        logging.error("Command '%s' is not implemented yet.", args.cmd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_parser().parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Now I have the problem that Tensorflow does parse command line arguments by itself (see [`tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_flags.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_flags.py)).

Is there a way to use `tf.app.flags` and parse the subcommand at the same time? So that within `tensorvision.train` it is still the same, although the command to run it was `tv train --whatever --flags --train --defines` instead of `train --whatever --flags --train --defines`?

Comment: A previous question on using argparse and Tensorflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120914/argparse-error-with-tensorflows-cifar10-py.

Comment: I don't know TensorFlow.  Is it `train.main()` that is running its own parser?  If so, how about editing `sys.argv` before making that call?  Maybe remove one or more strings, ones that you use, but it doesn't.

Comment: @hpaulj That could work. Do you know if it is possible to disable the unknown argument error of argparse?

Comment: `parse_known_args` handles unknown arguments gracefully.