# ArgumentError: argument --batch_size: conflicting option string: --batch_size in Spyder

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

During the execution of a lot of script with Spyder I get the error `ArgumentError: argument --batch_size: conflicting option string: --batch_size`
every time I try to execute the code and execution terminates.

Eg with Tensorflow CIFAR10 sample I get this error 
on this line

```
# Basic model parameters.
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
```

Full error log:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1344, in add_argument
    return self._add_action(action)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1707, in _add_action
    self._optionals._add_action(action)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1548, in _add_action
    action = super(_ArgumentGroup, self)._add_action(action)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1358, in _add_action
    self._check_conflict(action)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1497, in _check_conflict
    conflict_handler(action, confl_optionals)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1506, in _handle_conflict_error
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)

ArgumentError:  argument --batch_size: conflicting option string: --batch_size
```

I cannot figure how to fix it. If I run the code from command line the error doesn't happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argparse error with TensorFlow's cifar10.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120914/argparse-error-with-tensorflows-cifar10-py)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: you run the [cifar10.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py) more than once in the same python instance.

Cifar10.py has this code:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
```

which defines an argument `batch_size` in `tf.app.flags.FLAGS`.
When you run the Cifar10.py the second time (run the file itself or import through other file), TensorFlow checks that the argument `batch_size` already existed, so it gives the error.

**How to fix: open a new Console (Consoles->Open an IPython console) and run the file.**

The command line will create a new python instance every time, so you will not encounter this error.